# Perturbation factor terminology

Tags: terminology, linear-programming

This is a question about usage of English. I have an inequality $a^\textsf{T}x \leq b$, where $a$, $b$, and $x$ are vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Now, I want to perturb this inequality by a small amount $\varepsilon$. What is the correct name for this amount $\varepsilon$?

I am currently using *perturbation factor*, but this suggests a multiplicative perturbation rather than an additive one. Since I said I perturbed the inequality by an amount, I thought about *perturbation amount* as well, but sounds strange to me. Is there a correct terminology for this?

Comment: What about just "perturbation"?

Comment: @AC_MOSEK: I thought about that too, but I use "perturbation" as the process of perturbing a constraint.

Comment: I see your point, but I guess it should be clear from the context whether you are talking about the action or the amount....

Comment: I think you're right; I'm going to stick with just "perturbation". Thanks!